# what making a good soundtrack for social game

Tags: game-design, flash, sound

there are many successful social games in Facebook and other social sites like brain buddies, who has the biggest brain and word challenge.both of them have a great soundtrack while playing and in the beginning of the game . my question is how to find a good soundtrack or what's i should look for to find a good soundtrack like this that's help to attract the user specially for games that need concentration ?

Comment: There are languages without capitalisation and almost without punctuation, so if you consider grammar excusable, why not those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you already listed good examples of casual games with good background soundtracks. So play those games and pay attention to qualities of the music, such as the instruments used, tempo, volume compared to any other sounds in the game, notes/chords (major vs minor), and so on. Really pay attention to the subtleties that set the music apart from other background music; you might want to play other games where the music is distracting or the game is more action-oriented, and compare those qualities to see exactly what makes the social game music better for concentration and calmness.

Then apply these qualities that you have now noticed to your own music composition, or your search for background music, or convey the qualities to the person you are looking to hire to do your music.

Answer (score 1):

Its simply how you make the player feel he/she's inside the game by just listening to the music. The composer should know how to deliver the music depending on the environment and situation the scene offers.